# Information theory, a categorical perspective

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, it.information-theory

*Note: B-variables were called streams in a previous version -> you won't understand the comments otherwise*

#### Definition of $B$-variables

*Theorem:* Let $l_1\leq \dots\leq l_n$ be the lengths of a set of binary strings. If $\sum 2^{-l_i}\leq 1$, then we can hope no string is the prefix of an other in the set.

*Proof:* First, we notice that $1-\sum2^{-l_i}$ is a multiple of $2^{-l_n}$, such that adding $2^{l_{n}}-\sum2^{l_{n}-l_{i}}$ times $l_{n}$ to our set of lengths we get $\sum 2^{-l_i} = 1$. Then, if we prune an infinite binary tree at depths $l_1,\dots,l_n$, the set of paths from the root to the leafs described using left/right instructions will form a valid *prefix-distinct* set of binary strings.

Now, given a finite probability distribution $p$ and noting $l_i=\left\lceil -\log_{2}p_i\right\rceil$, you can check $\sum 2^{l_i}\leq 1$.

Given two finite random variables $X$ and $Y$, we can look at the family of distributions $(p_{X|Y=y})_{y\in \text{Im}(Y)}$ and construct the corresponding sets of binary strings using the $(l_i)$ defined above.

Then for each $(x, y)$ in $\text{Im}(X)\times \text{Im}(Y)$ we have an associated binary string (this is not injective). By drawing strings using $X$ and $Y$ in this way, we get a new random variable noted $B_{X|Y}$.

Similarly, we can look at $X$ and $B_{X|Y}$ and form the variable $B_{X|B_{X|Y}}$. To avoid nesting indices and to improve the notation we will omit the $B$ if we already are inside a $B$-variable such that $B_{X|(X|Y)} = B_{X|B_{X|Y}}$.

Given two finite random variables $X$ and $Y$, we can also consider the joint distribution $p_{X,Y}$. We can associate a string to each  $(x, y)$ in $\text{Im}(X)\times \text{Im}(Y)$ using this distribution and the usual $(l_i)$ and note the new random variable $B_{XY}$.

Finally, we can interpret $n$ independent draws of a random variable $X$ as the single draw of a variable with values in $\text{Im}(X)^n$ and we will note such variable $X^n$.

We generalize this notion differently to a $B$-variable: its $n^{th}$ power is obtained by taking the $n^{th}$ powers of the *non-$B$* variables composing it (recursively).

For example,

$$B_{X|(X|Y)}^ n = B_{X|B_{X|Y}}^n=B_{X^n|B_{X^n|Y^n}}$$

#### $B$-variables form a category

Using the right morphism definition, $B$-variables form a category $\textbf{Bvar}$.

A morphism of $B$-variables $X\to Y$ is given by two sequences of surjections $(e_n)$ and $(d_n)$ such that,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} Pr(e_n(X^n)=d_n(Y^n)) = 1 \tag{*}$$

and, using [Landau's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations),

$$H(d_n(Y^n))=H(Y^n)+o(n) \tag{**}$$

where $H$ denotes [Shannon's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).

To compose morphisms, we use the right inverses $(d_n^{-1})$ such that:

$$(e^{\prime}_n,d^{\prime}_n)\circ (e_n, d_n) = (e^{\prime}_n \circ d_n^{-1}\circ e_n, d^{\prime}_n)$$

Here, $(^{**})$ guarantees $(d_n^{-1})$ are "good-enough left inverses" to preserve $(^*)$ for the composite.

We must quotient the sequences $(e_n)$ and $(d_n)$ by $\lim H(e_n(X^n))/n$ and $\lim H(d_n(Y^n))/n$ to get identities (otherwise we only get right-identities -> thanks @Gro-Tsen).

*PS: The codomains of $(e_n)$ and $(d_n)$ must be the same because of $(^*)$ and must grow large enough with $n$ to satisfy $(^{**})$.*

#### Properties of $\textbf{Bvar}$

Given two finite random variables $X$ and $Y$, we have:
$${B_{X}}\to{B_{X|Y}}\to0$$

And we can define the *product*:
$${B_{X}}\times {B_{Y}}={B_{XY}}={B_{X(Y|X)}}={B_{Y(X|Y)}}$$
The *coproduct* is given by:
$${B_{X}}+ {B_{Y}}={B_{XY|(X|Y)(Y|X)}}={B_{XY|(Y|X)(X|Y)}}$$

The product corresponds to the [joint entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy) and the coproduct to the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

Shannon's [channel coding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem) is equivalent to proving the existence of coproducts in $\textbf{Bvar}$.

An *entropy* is a forgetful functor from $\textbf{Bvar}$ to $(\mathbb{R}^+,\leq)$.

*Disclaimer: I'm a software engineer without pure math education barely knowing some category theory. This seemed nice but I don't know what category theorist usually look for when finding a new category, hence my post here. What else can be said about $\bf{Bvar}$?*

Comment: What does "stream" mean?

Comment: Formally, they are objects of the $\bf{Stream}$ category build from the morphisms defined above. Informally you can think of them as bit streams generated from a finite random variable $X$ using an adaptative entropy encoder such that the rate of the stream approaches the entropy of $X$.

Comment: Where do these variables take their values? (In a finite set, I get it, but is it all in the same set or in a different set per variable?) Where do $d_n$ and $e_n$ take their values? What do $X^n$ and $Y^n$ mean? (I suppose they're not $n$-th powers, but a sequence of something, but if you're taking a sequence of i.i.d. variables, I don't see what role $n$ plays.) And now that you've clarified you're defining a category by its morphisms, you should specify how these morphisms are composed.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thank you for the remarks. I will try to edit this post later. The domain of $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets but they are not really relevant (they can be different) the codomains of $d_n$ and $e_n$ are the same since we compare $e_n(X^n)$ with $d_n(Y^n)$ and it is large enough to satisfy the condition on the entropy of $d_n(Y^n)$. $X^n$ and $Y^n$ are finite i.i.d. sequences of length $n$. Composition of morphisms is defined as $e^{\prime\prime}_n=e^{\prime}_n\circ d_n^{-1} \circ e_n$ and $d^{\prime\prime}_n=d^{\prime}_n$. I should add that the $(d_n)$ are injective.

Comment: The edit makes it better, but things are still confused. First, I don't see what role $X^n$ and $Y^n$ serve: maybe you *think* of things as an i.i.d. sequence, but you might as well write $Pr(e_n(X)=d_n(Y))$. More seriously, since the second term in your definition of composition is just $d'_n$, there can be no left-identity map, as is required in a category. Probably your morphisms aren't just pairs $(e_n,d_n)$ but equivalence classes of such pairs by some equivalence relation.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Why do we need $n$ ? Imagine a morphism from $\overline{P_{X}}$ to $\overline{P_{X|Y}}$. You cannot guess $H(X|Y)$ bits of $X|Y$ from $X$ alone with a small error probability but given $\epsilon > 0$ and a large enough $n$, you can guess $n(H(X|Y)-\epsilon)$ bits of $(X|Y)^n$ from $X^n$ alone almost certainly. This is why increasing the codewords length in error correcting codes decrease the error probability. My formulation of this insight might not be mathematically correct however.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thank you again for your remarks. I have updated the post. Indeed we need to quotient the pairs $(e_n, d_n)$ to get valid left-identities. Let me know if you have some more interrogations. :)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I have tried to justify the use of $n$ in the definition (2nd section). Let me know if this is clearer.

Comment: Would it be a more accurate summary of your work to say that 'the existence of prefix-free binary codes of mean length arbitrarily close to the entropy bound' is equivalent to 'coproducts in $\mathbf{Bvar}$'? (One could imagine other proofs of Shannon's NCT ...) As for your question, have you considered initial/terminal objects? Are there any reasonable endofunctors on $\mathbf{Bvar}$? If so, do they have adjoints? What is the information theoretic significance of products? It all looks interesting to me, but I won't  vote to reopen unless there is a more precise question.

Comment: @MarkWildon I would say no to your first question: 'the existence of prefix-free binary codes of mean length arbitrarily close to the entropy bound' is the source coding theorem but although I do construct prefix-free codes to define B-values that is not why coproduct exists for Bvar. I've written the best proof I know [here](https://matovitch.github.io/itcc/) (you can skip some parts).

Comment: @MarkWildon There is a feeling in information theory the | operator is acting as a projection reducing the entropy of the variable of the left by the knowledge of the variable on the right. But the projection of a random variable is not itself a random variable which prevents composition. I was aiming for an object were such projection could be composed. To answer your question the B-variable without entropy is a terminal object. One may be able to imagine an "original" entropy source (as /dev/random on linux) acting as initial object but I didn't think much about this. Fine to keep it closed.

Comment: @MarkWildon The existence of products in $\textbf{Bvar}$ is less interesting and only means that if from a stream you are able to reproduce two other streams produced by $X$ and $Y$ you are able to reproduce the compressed interleaved stream $B_{XY}$ from the initial stream (hence it has at least a rate of $H(X)+H(Y|X)$). For the reasonable endofunctors I don't have a lot of ideas, I will try to think about it. This might not be really interesting hence I'm fine updating a closed question with my remaining thoughts even though MO might isn't meant to be used as a note-taking app. ^^